# Show the limit of this function goes to a function of $e$.

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I need to show that this lim goes to a function of e, namely $e^\frac{t^2}{2}$. I'm not sure if l'hospital's rule is needed. This is involved in the proof that the gamma distribution goes to the normal distribution (if anyone is interested). thanks!

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty}{e^{-t{\sqrt x}}\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt x}\right)^{-x} }$$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Try $u=\sqrt x$

Comment: Is $t$ supposed to be positive?

Comment: Dr. Graubner, I believe t just needs to be less than or equal to the square root of x. And x is positive.

Answer (score 1):

The first-order approximation here is that $\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{-x}\approx e^{t\sqrt{x}}$. Multiply that by $e^{-t\sqrt{x}}$, and we just get $1$. Clearly, this wasn't precise enough for our purposes.

All right, we need a better approximation like that. First, products are annoying to deal with, so let's take logarithms; if $L$ is the limit we seek,
$$\begin{align} \ln L & = \ln \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-t\sqrt{x}}\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{-x} \\& = \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln \left (  e^{-t\sqrt{x}}\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{-x} \right ) \\
 & = \lim_{x\to\infty} -t\sqrt{x} -x\ln\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{x}}\right) \end{align}$$
Next, let's get rid of those square roots; substitute $y=\sqrt{x}$:
$$\ln L = \lim_{y\to\infty} -ty - y^2\ln\left(1-\frac ty\right)$$
From here - we could do something with L'Hopital's rule, but I greatly prefer power series as a tool, especially since we need more than just the first term.
\begin{align*}\ln\left(1-\frac ty\right) &= -\frac ty - \frac12\cdot\frac{t^2}{y^2} - \frac13\cdot \frac{t^3}{y^3}-\cdots\\
\ln L &= \lim_{y\to\infty} -ty -y^2\left(-\frac ty - \frac12\cdot\frac{t^2}{y^2} - \frac13\cdot \frac{t^3}{y^3}-\cdots\right)\\
\ln L &= \lim_{y\to\infty} -ty +ty + \frac12\cdot t^2 + \frac13\cdot\frac{t^3}{y}+\cdots\\
\ln L &= \lim_{y\to\infty} \frac12\cdot t^2 + \frac13\cdot\frac{t^3}{y}+\cdots = \frac12t^2\\
L &= e^{\frac12t^2}\end{align*}

Comment: Good answer. +1. Kindly check whether my edit is correct or not @jmerry.

Comment: I would have gone with a simpler correction (just adding the $\ln$ to the one term that really needed it), but I approve. On a typographic note - I'm consistent about not using periods on centered equation lines. I'm removing those.

Comment: Thank you very much @jmerry for your verification.